# Issue in finding element on a webpage

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, qwebelement

The id for webelement is `mainPage:mainForm:j_id152:locationsPage:locsBlock:slTable:0:locNamePanel`

**The problem is:**

To find a WebElement. When hovered upon that webelement, Edit link comes up which needs to be clicked.

**Tried this approach:**

1. Scrolling the webpage down (just in case)
2. Finding the webElement by id
3. Getting the X and Y coordinates for that webElement
4. Using mouseover

**Following is the code:**

```
//Finding the Webelement coordinates
int X= driver.findElement(By.id("mainPage:mainForm:j_id152:locationsPage:locsBlock:slTable:0:locNamePanel")).getLocation().getX();
int Y= driver.findElement(By.id("mainPage:mainForm:j_id152:locationsPage:locsBlock:slTable:0:locNamePanel")).getLocation().getY();
System.out.println("The coordinates are:-" +X +"---"+Y);
Robot robot = new Robot(); 

//Doing a mouse over for the X and Y coordinates
robot.mouseMove(X, Y);

//Clicking the Edit button
driver.findElement(By.id("mainPage:mainForm:j_id152:locationsPage:locsBlock:slTable:0:j_id207")).click();
```

**Issue:**

The X and Y coordinates are coming back (not sure if those are for the WebElement that I am looking for). But, the mouseover isn't working.

Comment: I guess I figured out the issue. The mouseMove is actually looking for the X & Y coordinates on the entire screen and not the page itself. Is there any other function which would just look for the coordinates on the active web driver page?

Comment: a lot of "badness" emanating from this script. don't ever use coords for web automation, and don't delegate to the `Robot` class if you don't have to. If you need to hover, use the `Actions` class.

Comment: Thanks, i already did that.
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("mainPage:mainForm:j_id152:locationsPage:locsBlock:slTable:0:locNamePanel"))).click().build().perform();
WebElement subLink = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("mainPage:mainForm:j_id152:locationsPage:locsBlock:slTable:0:j_id207")));
actions.moveToElement(subLink);
actions.click();
actions.perform();

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you do something like the following:

```
//Finding the WebElement
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("mainPage:mainForm:j_id152:locationsPage:locsBlock:slTable:0:locNamePanel"));
Actions actionsProvider = new Actions(driver);
actionsProvider.moveToElement(element).perform();

//Clicking the Edit button
driver.findElement(By.id("mainPage:mainForm:j_id152:locationsPage:locsBlock:slTable:0:j_id207")).click();
```

This should accomplish the same thing without having to rely on the Java Robot classes.